# Testng:Dataprovider: error : sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl@2f1ea80d

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse

I am trying to read data from excel which contains only one column with three rows in it

ID
A1002
B1003
C1004

I am using dataprovider in Testng to achieve the same. But on returning the 2D Object array, I am getting sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl@2f1ea80d error

```
 @DataProvider(name = "getLoginData")
    public Object[][] LoginData() throws Exception
 {
     Workbook workbook = null;
     ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

     FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path_TestData);
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(Home.sheetname);
        int rows = ExcelWSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        System.out.println("Rows is" +rows);
        for(int i=1; i<rows; i++)
        {
            XSSFRow row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(i);
            values.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
        }
        System.out.println("value size is" +values.size());
        Object[][] returnValue = new Object[10][10];

        for(i=0; i<values.size();i++)
        {

            returnValue[i][0] = values.get(i);

        }
                return returnValue;

 }

@Test(dataProvider="getLoginData")
    public void LoginData(String ID)
    {

          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='select']")).click();
      //clicking on the ID selected in dropdown         
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()=ID]")).click();
     }
```

Comment: Which jars are you using Apache POI or JExcel?

Comment: @Dev : XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile) means POI.

Comment: @kushal. Can you update which type of file are you using (.xls) or (.xlsx)? Thanks

Comment: XSSF deals with (.xlsx) while hssf deals with (.xls).

Comment: @Kushal : Thanks for looking into the issue. I tried the below code but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, I've made few adjustments here and there:

```
 @DataProvider(name = "getLoginData")
  public static Object[][] LoginData() throws Exception
  {
    XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook = null;
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\kushal8\\Desktop\\K1.xlsx");
    ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
    XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int rows = ExcelWSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    System.out.println("Rows is" +rows);
    for(int i=1; i<rows; i++)
    {
        XSSFRow row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(i);
        values.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
    }
    System.out.println("value size is" +values.size());
    Object[][] returnValue = new Object[15][15];

    for(int i=0; i<values.size();i++)
    {

        returnValue[i][0] = values.get(i);

        //System.out.println(returnValue[i][0]);

    }
    return returnValue;

}
```